# how do we convert from a dynamic object to a concrete object>?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm attempting to explicitly convert a `dynamic` type to a concrete type and getting the following:

> Newtonsoft.Json: Can not convert from System.DateTimeOffset to
> System.DateTime.

I have the following concrete model:

```
public class RtfTiffMatchModel : TableEntity
{
    public RtfTiffMatchModel()
    {
    }

    public string visitId { get; set; }
    public DateTime rtfReceivedAt { get; set; }
    public string rtfFilename { get; set; }
    public DateTime tifReceivedAt { get; set; }
    public string tifFilename { get; set; }
    public string rtfRowKey { get; set; }
    public string tifRowKey { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a this dynamic type:

```
{
  "visitId": "bbbb-2021-11305",
  "rtfReceivedAt": "2021-11-15T17:45:10.2006842Z",
  "rtfFilename": "usap_abs_adams_alex_10202021_bbbb-2021-11305_000_111_20211024.rtf",
  "tifReceivedAt": "2021-11-15T17:45:10.2006842Z",
  "tifFilename": "usap_ar_adams_alex_10202021_bbbb-2021-11305_000_111_20211024_0800.tif",
  "rtfRowKey": "FromjjjvilleBbbBilling",
  "tifRowKey": "FromjjjvilleBbbBilling",
  "PartitionKey": "FromjjjvilleBbbBilling",
  "RowKey": "68955313-8f66-4bf0-ad6d-abf635bdb537",
  "Timestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
  "$AzureWebJobsParentId": "e9d2e73d-170a-4367-9c4f-4beb054e79e5"
}
```

I'm attempting to convert the above `dynamic` type to `RtfTiffMatchModel`:

```
        var rtfTiffMatch = new RtfTiffMatchModel { PartitionKey = match.PartitionKey,
            RowKey = match.RowKey,
            rtfReceivedAt = (DateTime)match.rtfReceivedAt,
            rtfFilename = match.rtfFilename,
            rtfRowKey = match.RowKey,
            tifFilename = match.tifFilename,
            tifReceivedAt = (DateTime)match.ReceivedAt,
            tifRowKey = match.RowKey,
            visitId = match.visitId };
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do I convert this to a concrete type?*

Comment: `(DateTime)match.rtfReceivedAt` is throwing your error. Newtonsoft thinks `match.rtfReceivedAt` is a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0). `((DateTimeOffset)match.rtfReceivedAt).DateTime` should work as a quick/dirty fix. See [Converting between DateTime and DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset#conversions-from-datetimeoffset-to-datetime).

Comment: @DM please make that an answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> `(DateTime)match.rtfReceivedAt` is throwing your error. Newtonsoft thinks `match.rtfReceivedAt` is a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0). `((DateTimeOffset)match.rtfReceivedAt).DateTime` should work as a quick/dirty fix. See [Converting between DateTime and DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset#conversions-from-datetimeoffset-to-datetime).

Note that you appear to have a typo at `tifReceivedAt: (DateTime)match.ReceivedAt`. There is no `ReceivedAt` property on your dynamic object. [Here's a dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bqNu2V) showing the conversion working.